# Regex to find a string from last occurrence of a character to a number or [

Tags: regex

I have a text

```
Word_1 (string_2)! String_3 - String_4 X_1:X_2
```

where `String_2`, `String_3` and `String_4` can have one or multiple words (with numbers also, like `aaa b32`), while X_1 and X_2 can be a single digit number or a `[` (followed by a single digit number and a `]`, so something like `9:[4]` or `[9]:4`).

And this regex (used inside an Android app) for matching String_4 (so the string between `-`  and X_1:

```
(?<=\-\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s)?
```

It works fine, but I've just realized that String_2 can also contains '- ' (for example `String_2 = aaa - bbb ccc`) so I need to fix my regex for starting from last occurrence of `-`  (and again ending before X_1, considering that String_4 can have numbers as well).

How to do that?

I've tried `(?:[^\-](?!(\-)))+$` but I can't find a way for avoiding the   after `-` and to stop at X_1.

Thanks!

Comment: Would `(?<=- )[^-]+?(?=\s\[?\d]?_)` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this `9:[4] or [9]:4` is the only allowed format after String_4, and String_2 is between parenthesis, you can assert only the allowed chars after the match until the end of the string.

```
(?<=-\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s)?(?=[][:\s\d]*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tEjcTD/1)

Or use a bit more precise match with for example a capturing group instead of lookarounds and matching 1 or more words for String_4:

```
-\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\s+(?:\d+:\[\d+]|\[\d+]:\d)$
```

**Explanation**

- `-\s` Match `-` and a whitspace char
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed ranges
  - `(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ chars from the character class to match multiple words
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d+:\[\d+]` Match the `9:[4]` format
  - `|` Or
  - `\[\d+]:\d` Match the `[9]:4` format
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J3Ahdv/1)

Comment: Thanks! They both works fine, but I'm going for the second one (in case some day String_2 will change)

Answer (score 0):

What about adding in your regexp a negative lookup to exclude strings followed by "-"?

```
(?<=\-\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s(?!\-)([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s)?
```